# toString method for a doubly linked list using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
 public String recursiveToString()
  {
    DoubleLinkedListNode<T> current = first;
    String list = "";

    if(current == null)
    {
      return "";
    }
    else
    {
      list += current.info + ", ";
      current = current.next;
      return list + recursiveToString();
    }
  }
```

It is supposed to print out the list when I run the code but it just crashes every time it runs. This is everything that I've tried to do so far.

Comment: You are resetting current to first every call, you'll probably want to pass that into the function, you are also resetting the list variable each time.

Comment: Welcome on SO! First of, it would be nice if you could tag the language that you used. Also, try to provide more details about your issue. Just saying that "it just crashes" is pretty vague. Do you see a stack overflow exception? A null reference exception? That kind of information can be very valuable when trying to figuring out where the problem is in your code. Have a great stay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you'll want to pass the current position in the list back into the function each time, so change your signature to this:

```
public String recursiveToString(DoubleLinkedListNode<T> current)
```

Then alter your code a bit so it uses that and continues to pass it down, the list variable is also unnecessary, the recursion will take care of concatenating everything:

```
public String recursiveToString(DoubleLinkedListNode<T> current)
{
    if(current == null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return current.info + " " + recursiveToString(current.next);
    }
}
```

If you would like to do it without changing the signature of the function, just rename the function I have above and create the definition for your parameterless function like so:

```
public String recursiveToString()
{
    return aboveFunction(first);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to rewrite the code without passing any parameters?

Comment: Yes, see my edit, you'll still want the function I have defined, your parameterless function will simply call it passing in the first element